# How can I get an export of stories/bugs in all releases for a date range?

Tags: jira

I'm looking to get the following data for a given date range:

- Release Date
- Release Version
- Number of Stories
- Number of Bugs

I understand that it's easy to get this information one release at a time by using the Releases area, however in order to get the information above, you need to drill into each release.  I'm looking to get this information in the form of "rows of data"

For lack of available tags:  Jira Cloud

Example Output

```
ReleaseDate,Version,Stories,Bugs
1/1/2017,4.5.0.0,6,2
1/7/2017,4.5.1.0,4,3
1/12/2017,4.5.2.0,9,0
1/13/2017,4.5.3.0,0,1
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to simply highlight the releases that you want and then open in **Issue Navigator**.

**Export Method**

Simply export as an XLS specifying the columns that you require.

Failing that, export all columns and simply delete the redundant ones.

**Command Method**

If you are seeking that information within JIRA itself without an export than you are going to require a few nifty JIRA SQL commands which you can save as a filter.

I will update later with the exact commands but for now you can find a wealth of information in the JQL overview by Atlassian.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql

The commands that you require are:

```
project = INSERTPROJECTHERE AND issuetype in (Bug, Story) AND fixVersion = "INSERTVERSIONHERE"
```

Or you can try

```
project = INSERTPROJECTHERE AND issuetype in (Bug, Story) AND status was Resolved during (INSERTSTARTDATE, INSERTENDDATE)
```

**Dashboard Method**

Create a dashboard, or add to an existing dashboard the widget **Issue Statistics** and then specify the date range that you require.  It will pull in all releases, bugs and stories during that period.

Comment: Would any of these methods get me rows of data in this format though:

date,version,stories,bugs
1/1/2017,v1.2.0.0,6,2

Comment: HI David, they will be exported in tabular format, yes.  How you then display that tabled information in a spreadsheet program is up to you (columns, rows, pivot table, etc).  Simply go to the Issue Navigator, select Export and then select the columns and simply choose the columns you require.

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman give those new commands a try that I updated the answer with.

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman give those new commands a try that I updated the answer with.  Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately none seem to give me the results in the format that I was looking for.  I'm aware that I can export and do some excel work to get it in my format, but I was curious if it was possible in JIRA by itself.

Comment: Rows of data:

releaseDate,version,numberOfStories,numberOfBugs

Comment: One release per row

Comment: Sorry Brian; I am unclear what you are asking.  You want a release to be the row and then the Issue Count to be in the column?  Or you want a list of issues in the column?

Comment: BrianDavidBerman If you just want this "in JIRA" as opposed to being exported you can always just take the filter suggested by @Venture2099 and make it a saved filter, then share it with the person who needs it. This has the added advantage of being dynamically updated.

Comment: I've updated my question with the example output.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the permission you have to access the JIRA board you should have an option  to expand more filters and select date filter (CreateDate in my case for example). notice I am also not able to access 192 hidden filters.

> Blockquote

[image]

> you should be able to filter something like below.

[image]